# No me toma el valor del radiobuton dentro de un modal

Tags: jquery

tengo un problema estoy haciendo un modal donde al abrir me muestra 5 radio buton (tipos de viviendas)

```
<div class="row" id="viviendas"></div>
```

1. Casa
2. Departamento
3. Parcela
4. Chalet
5. Otro

Y tengo un div oculto:

```
<div class="row" id="otros" style="display: none">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Especifique</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="otro"></textarea>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el modal que genero.  Mi código viene dentro de un json y lo armo de la siguiente manera, no puse todos los radio para no hacer tan extenso el codigo

```
$('.btn').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            sit = $(this).attr('href');
            url="AQUI VA MI RUTA DONDE CARGO DATOS EN EL MODAL";
            $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#formModal').attr('action', sit);
                $('#modal').modal('toggle');
                if(!data.Estado){
                    alert("Error inesperado");
                }else{
                   xR = "";
                    $('#viviendas').html('');
                        xR+='<div class="col-sm-12">';
                            xR+='<div class="form-group">';
                            xR+='<div class="form-check">';
                            xR+='<label class="form-check-label">';
                            xR+='<input type="radio" name="tipo" value="1" checked>';
                            xR+='<span>CASA</span>';
                            xR+='</label>';
                            xR+='</div>';
                            xR+='</br>';
                            xR+='<div class="form-check">';
                            xR+='<label class="form-check-label">';
                            xR+='<div class="form-check">';
                            xR+='<label class="form-check-label">';
                            xR+='<input type="radio" name="tipo" value="5" checked>';
                            xR+='<span>OTROS</span>';
                            xR+='</label>';
                            xR+='</div>';
                            xR+='</div>';
                            xR+='</div>';
                    $('#viviendas').append(xR);
                    xR = "";
                }
            });
        });
```

Mi problema se genera a continuación, ya que div oculto cuando pincho otro me deberia mostrar el textarea, pero no hay caso que el value me llegue a este último código que pongo

```
$("input[name=tipo]").change(function () {
                alert($(this).val()); // ESTE ALERT NUNCA SE ME EJECUTA
                if($(this).val()==1){
                    $('#otros').hide();
                }else if($(this).val()==2){
                    $('#otros').hide();
                }else if($(this).val()==3){
                    $('#otros').show();
                }else if($(this).val()==5){
                    $('#otros').show();
                }
            });
```

como puedo lograr que radio entre y se ejecute `$("input[name=tipo]").change(function ()`  en este codigo, ya que el alert no me arroja nada, o existe otra forma de rescatar ese ID que necesito, por favor que alguien me oriente a solucionar esto

Answer (score 0):

intenta agregando la la funcion change dentro de donde llamas al model

```
$('.btn').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
sit = $(this).attr('href');
url="AQUI VA MI RUTA DONDE CARGO DATOS EN EL MODAL";
$.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#formModal').attr('action', sit);
    $('#modal').modal('toggle');
    if(!data.Estado){
        alert("Error inesperado");
    }else{
       xR = "";
        $('#viviendas').html('');
            xR+='<div class="col-sm-12">';
                xR+='<div class="form-group">';
                xR+='<div class="form-check">';
                xR+='<label class="form-check-label">';
                xR+='<input type="radio" name="tipo" value="1" checked>';
                xR+='<span>CASA</span>';
                xR+='</label>';
                xR+='</div>';
                xR+='</br>';
                xR+='<div class="form-check">';
                xR+='<label class="form-check-label">';
                xR+='<div class="form-check">';
                xR+='<label class="form-check-label">';
                xR+='<input type="radio" name="tipo" value="5" checked>';
                xR+='<span>OTROS</span>';
                xR+='</label>';
                xR+='</div>';
                xR+='</div>';
                xR+='</div>';
        $('#viviendas').append(xR);
        xR = "";
        
        
        $("input[name=tipo]").change(function () {
            alert($(this).val()); // ESTE ALERT NUNCA SE ME EJECUTA
            if($(this).val()==1){
                $('#otros').hide();
            }else if($(this).val()==2){
                $('#otros').hide();
            }else if($(this).val()==3){
                $('#otros').show();
            }else if($(this).val()==5){
                $('#otros').show();
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: También lo hice, he movido $('input:radio[name=tipo]').change(function (){ dentro de la misma funcion y tampoco me resultó, por eso he buscado ayuda, ya que de ninguna forma me esta funcionado

Comment: Por favor siempre agrega una explicacion a tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que como estas creando elementos html dinamicos. debes de agregar el evento a estos.
para mas informacion revisa [https://api.jquery.com/on/](http://documentacion%20de%20jquery%20ON())

Intentalo de esta manera

```
$( "body" ).on( "change", "input[name=tipo]",function () {
            alert($(this).val()); // ESTE ALERT NUNCA SE ME EJECUTA
            if($(this).val()==1){
                $('#otros').hide();
            }else if($(this).val()==2){
                $('#otros').hide();
            }else if($(this).val()==3){
                $('#otros').show();
            }else if($(this).val()==5){
                $('#otros').show();
            }
        });
```